# Can you combine case and top statements to label which values are in the top few (Microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of fees to summarise, where each fee is used repeatedly over time. My project is to sum the value of each fee over a year, and to label which of these are in the top 80 by value, and which aren't. I need two columns, one with the fee code, and the other with a 'yes/no' value for if the fee is in the top 80 or not.

I've tried the following code, which doesn't work, and I get the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

I'm a self-taught programmer, so probably missing something obvious!

Many thanks for your advice on this.

Stuart

```
select 
    hCODE as 'Fee Code',
    case 
       when hCODE in (select top 80 hCODE, sum(hPRICE) 
                      from dbo.History
                      where hDONE >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
                      group by hCODE
                      order by sum(hPRICE) desc) 
          then 'Top 80' 
          else 'Other' 
    end as 'In Top 80'
from 
    dbo.History;
```

Comment: SQL Server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this code in the `when` condition:

```
when hCODE in (select top 80 hCODE, sum(hPRICE) 
               .....
```

Your `select` returns **two columns** for each row of the result set - but you're checking to see whether **one value** (`hCODE`) is in this set. You cannot return two values from the subquery here - just the one that your `hCODE` is being compared against.

Answer (score 0):

A row-numbering + windowing solution will be far more efficient than your existing subquery:

```sql
select 
    hCODE as [Fee Code],
    case 
       when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalPerCode DESC) <= 80
          then 'Top 80' 
          else 'Other' 
    end as [In Top 80]
from 
    (SELECT *, SUM(hPRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY hCODE) AS TotalPerCode
    FROM dbo.History
    where hDONE >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
) h;
```

You can also do this with a `GROUP BY` as you only want the `hCODE` value:

```sql
select 
    hCODE as [Fee Code],
    case 
       when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalPerCode DESC) <= 80
          then 'Top 80' 
          else 'Other' 
    end as [In Top 80]
from 
    (SELECT hCODE, SUM(hPRICE) AS TotalPerCode
    FROM dbo.History
    where hDONE >= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
    GROUP BY hCODE
) h;
```

You should use `[]` to quote column names with spaces, not `''`